# get 8 digit random alphanumeric from uuid python and django

Tags: python, django, random, uuid

Basically in python there are some ways to get a random number with fixed digits like by using `random` module

But here i am using python's uuid module to generate a random string like below

```
id = uuid.uuid4()
print id
UUID('decbb83f-9c35-4c37-a3d9-69e89bd8dd73')
```

But i want only 8 digit number from the above random UUID object

We can do something like

```
print str(id).split('-')[0]
```

which was not a UUID object but a string here

I am going to use this 8 digit random UUID(object) number in django UUID field like below

```
uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

So how to get only 8 digit alphanumeric random UUID object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible since a UUID is a 16-byte but you can generate a unique string of 8 chars.

If you look at UUIDField class in django model field,the max length sets to be 32.You don't have option specify max_length in **kwargs

```
   def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 32
        super(UUIDField, self).__init__(verbose_name, **kwargs)
```